# How to select images in a range depending on two trackBars selected values?

Tags: c#, winforms

The main goal is to use both trackBars as range selector.

For now the way the code is looks like i messed a bit the whole logic with the selection range.

I have two trackBars.

When I make double click on one of them it's coloring both each one in another color.
The one in red is the starting selection of the range the green is the end selection.

For example if the red one value is 5 and the green value is 10 then in the List selected there should be all the images in values 5 to 10 including 5 and including 10 this images from the array images.

The selection/s should be valid only after making double click on one of them not just when scrolling or changing values but first making double click on one of them. The double click is line activation to get into the selection mode.

[image: selection]

In the screenshot example the range is between 9 and 24 including 9 and 24.
So form the array images i want to take all the files from 9 to 24 including 9 and 24 and add them to the List selected.

The confirmation button will make the adding from the array to the list.

The problem is how to make the selection/s in the double click event when making first time double click it should make the current values as start and end value and then calculate the range and then changing the start and end and the range if moving one of them values.

In the end when clicking the confirmation button then add the selection range from the array to the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class Editor : Form
    {
        private int startSelection;
        private int endSelection;
        private List<string> selected = new List<string>();
        private string[] images;
        private int oldValue;

        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            images = GetImages();
            macTrackBar1.Maximum = images.Length - 1;
            macTrackBar2.Maximum = images.Length - 1;
            macTrackBar2.Value = macTrackBar2.Maximum;
            oldValue = macTrackBar1.Value;
        }

        private void Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        public string[] GetImages()
        {
            string rootPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"d:\downloaded images\Radar");
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath).GetDirectories()
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreationTimeUtc)
                .First();
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.gif");

            images = files.Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();

            Array.Sort(images, new MyComparer(true));

            return images;
        }

        private class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            public static readonly MyComparer Descending = new MyComparer(false);

            [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);

            public int Compare(string psz1, string psz2)
            {
                return (Reverse ? -1 : 1) * StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2);
            }

            public MyComparer(bool reverse)
            {
                Reverse = reverse;
            }

            public bool Reverse { get; private set; }
        }

        private void macTrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, decimal value)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[(int)value]);

            startSelection = macTrackBar1.Value;
            endSelection = macTrackBar2.Value;
        }

        private void macTrackBar1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleF macTrackerRect = macTrackBar1._trackerRect;

            if(macTrackerRect.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                macTrackBar2.TrackerColor = Color.Green;
                macTrackBar1.TrackerColor = Color.Red;

                startSelection = macTrackBar1.Value;
                endSelection = macTrackBar2.Value;

                selected.Add(images[startSelection]);
                selected.Add(images[endSelection]);
            }
        }

        private void macTrackBar2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            RectangleF macTrackerRect = macTrackBar2._trackerRect;

            if (macTrackerRect.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                macTrackBar2.TrackerColor = Color.Green;
                macTrackBar1.TrackerColor = Color.Red;

                startSelection = macTrackBar1.Value;
                endSelection = macTrackBar2.Value;

                selected.Add(images[startSelection]);
                selected.Add(images[endSelection]);
            }
        }

        private void macTrackBar2_ValueChanged(object sender, decimal value)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[(int)value]);

            startSelection = macTrackBar1.Value;
            endSelection = macTrackBar2.Value;
        }

        private void btnConfirmation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var tt = images.Skip(startSelection).Take(endSelection
                - startSelection);
        }
    }
}
```

In the bottom in the confirmation button event click i calculate and take out the images from the images array.

this screenshot show the result after clicking the confirmation button

[image: resluts]

Comment: Are the images in the array you're selecting from already sorted into the right indices? Meaning, does taking 9 - 24, inclusive, mean you just want the `selected` list to contain images (`string`s?) currently stored in indices 9 - 24 in the `images` array? If so, why not something like `images.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex)`, which might be *off by one*, but that's the general gist. What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you set the `startSelection` and `endSelection` in `btnConfirmation_Click`? Where you need to use them to proceed. Or are you using them instantly somewhere else in your code? Note the `MouseDoubleClick` event might (if the value has changed) also invoke the `Scroll` and `ValueChanged` events. And you should `pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();` before you assign a new one.

Comment: @CoolBots i changed both staertSelection and endSelection to be int variables then in the confirmation button event i tried var tt = images.Skip(startSelection).Take(endSelection
                - startSelection); and if for example the startSelection is 9 and the endSelection is 24 in the variable tt i get 15 string images but they are starting from image 11 to image 25 so in index 0 the image 11 and in index 14 image 25 but it should be at index 0 image 9 and in the last index it should be image 24

Comment: @CoolBots i just edited my question with the new code changed both startSelection and endSelection to be int variables like indexs. then added another screenshot showing the result of images taken out from the images array when clicking the confirmation button when the startSelection is 9 and the endSelection is 24.

Comment: Can you please confirm that your `GetImages` method returns the array sorted in the order you'd expect? Meaning, `image3` is in `images[2]` spot, etc, presuming the first name is `image1`?